# Jordan form of different matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Suppose you have a 4x4 matrix with the characteristic polynomial equal to the minimal polynomial $m_F(x)=C_F(x)=(x-3)^2(x+2)^2$. Find the Jordan form.

Is this the correct solution?
$$
M=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 &-2
\end{array}\right]
$$

> Find the Jordan form of A
>   $$
> A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0\\
> 0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right]
> $$

To find the Jordan we need to find:

(a) The eigenvalues

since its an upper triangular matrix, then the elements on the diagonal matrix are the eigenvalues. Hence $C_A(\alpha)=\alpha^5\implies \alpha=0$

(b) Find the minimal polynomial $m_A(\alpha)$

We note that $m_A(A)=A^3=0$. hence, $m_A(alpha)=\alpha^3$ (I know the observation is correct, but not sure how to get the minimal polynomial)

(c)$d=dim(E_{alpha=0})$

$dim(null(A-0I))=dim(Null(A))=3
Now, we conclude that we need 3 jordan block and the first block is of size 3x3, hence:

so, $A=J^3\oplus J^1\oplus J^1$

IS my solution correct. I find forming jordan forms confusing .

> Find the Jordan form of B
>   $$
> B=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
> 0 & 0 & 0& 1\\
> 0 & 0 & 0& 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0  & 0 &0
> \end{array}\right]
> $$

To find the Jordan we need to find:

(a) The eigenvalues

since its an upper triangular matrix, then the elements on the diagonal matrix are the eigenvalues. Hence $C_B(\alpha)=\alpha^4\implies \alpha=0$

(b) Find the minimal polynomial $m_B(\alpha)$

We note that $m_B(B)=B^2=0$. hence, $m_B(alpha)=\alpha^2$

(c)$d=dim(E_{alpha=0})$

$dim(null(B-0I))=dim(Null(B))=1
Now, we conclude that we need 1 jordan block and the first block is of size 2x2, but that can't be?

Comment: $Rank(A-0I)^0=5$, $Rank(A-0I)^1=3,$ $Rank(A-0I)^2=1,$   $Rank (A-0I)^3=0.$     Look at the differences, you get a "dot diagram"  $2,2,1.$   This means your JCF is of type $J_3 \oplus J_2.$

Comment: I don't know what is a dot diagram

Comment: Ultimately, the JCF can be computed by examining the generalized eigenvectors.  The rank differences 2,2,1 tell you have 2 eigenvectors of (rank 1), 2 generalized eigenvectors of rank 2, and 1 generalized eigenvector of rank 3.

Comment: how to define A^0?

Comment: $A^0=I$ (by convention)

Comment: how did you make the connection between the rank of the eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors and the jordan blocks? I followed until you said This means your JCF is of type $J_3\oplus J_2$.

Comment: 2 Gen. E-vect. of rank 1 means  2 Blocks Total.    
2 Gen. E-vect. of rank 2 means   2 Blocks of size $\geq 2.$  
1 Gen. E-vect of rank 3 means   1 Block of size $\geq 3.$    Thus you have blocks of size 3,2.

Comment: Just for completion: 2 eigenvectors of rank 1 means we have two blocks of size at least 1(It also means that the total # of blocks is 2). 2 generalized eigenvectors of rank 2 means we have two blocks of size at least 2. 1 generalized eigenvector of rank 3 means we have 1 block of size at least 3. Going backward, this means 1 block of size 3 and 2 blocks of size 2.

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is correct.

For the second, as a quick check look for permutations of columns and rows (same permutation)
and see if it results in a nice Jordan form. In this case, with
$\pi = (1,3,5,2,4)$ let $P$ be the corresponding permutation matrix $P e_k = e_{\pi_k}$, then
$P^T A P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1\\
0&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, so we see that there are two blocks of sizes 2,3.

For the third question, take $\pi = (1,4,3,2)$ and let $Q$ be the corresponding permutation matrix, then
$Q^T B Q = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0&  0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$, so we see that there is one Jordan block of size 2 and the rest are of size one.